# Tie-breaking implementation on geth

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I'm analysing `geth`'s source code for my undergraduate thesis, and I'm unable to locate the tie-breaking function, i.e. where blocks are compared and either become canonical or uncle. My final goal is to try to implement a little change to that function, based on timestamp comparison. Any help is most appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You may also want to try their Discord https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#contribution Please post here if you get an answer: it's totally OK to post your own answer. Good luck!

Comment: I'd start from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/blockchain.go, and the consensus rules are in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/consensus.

Answer (score 0):

It's located at the final lines of https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/core/forkchoice.go. That's where forks are decided.